# JS return value of a nested .then

Tags: javascript

I know this has been asked but specifically here I'm dealing with a nested .then.
I have the following function:

```
function somethingCreate() {
  getMainThemeId();
  .then(result => alert(result))
}

function getMainThemeId() {
  shopify.theme
    .list()
    .then(themes => {
      let theme = themes.find(o => o.role === 'main');
      return theme;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err.response.body));
}
```

The method somethingCreate is going to contain more methods so I need the result of getMainThemeId.  shopify.theme is an api module I'm working with and it properly returns the results for theme.  The problem is I'm stuck on returning that to the method somethingCreate().  Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You forgot to return the Promise from `getMainThemeId`

Comment: I added return theme in there and it still doesn't work for me.  The recommended answer has an explanation about how it's "magic" . @CertainPerformance

Comment: It should work - you just need to make sure `getMainThemeId` returns the Promise chain, which you're not doing now

Comment: Works now.  Got it figured out.